# What is wrong with this batch processing of the contents of a text file

Tags: batch-file

This is how I have always remembered processing the CONTENTS of a file line-by-line in a batch file (backed up by web search):

```
for /F "delims=" %%N in ("del files.txt") do del "%%N"
```

It now deletes `"del files.txt"` and `@echo %%N` gives `"del files.txt"`

Does it have something to do with the name needing to be quoted because of the space? WTF am I missing?

Comment: You refusal to read help is your problem. Your code does what you are telling it to do. Print your string to the screen in a round about way. From Help `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command [command-parameters]`. **So it is not the way to parse a file.** See `for /?`.

Comment: Hint: `UseBackQ`.

Comment: Please don't accuse me of not reading help.

A. I have used hatt exact syntax in other working batch files.I went and checked an in each case, %1 or an environment var were in ()
B:for /?:
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('string') DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (`command`) DO command [command-parameters]

Comment: Finishing my comment

  C #1 google search result: https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

I am asking why quotes can't be used in (file-set) when they are required for spaces and used in file-set without /F

Comment: Thank you double-beep for actually providing help rather than false accusations to feel superior.

Comment: And I had read help on usebackq but apparently misunderstood it. I hope my misunderstanding serves to help someone else in the future

Comment: @jmkse if my answer was helpful, please accept it. Also, when you are not using `usebackq`, you can include filename without quotes, but the command will fail if the filename contains spaces. So, if you quote, system will think it is a string. That is why `usebackq` is used.

Comment: You can also get around this by never ever ever using spaces in filenames.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`("string")` is used to parse strings. `("filename")` can be used with `usebackq`. It seems you confused them in your search. So, you can write:

```bat
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%N IN ("del files.txt") do whatever you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please** don't accuse me of not reading help.

1. for /? (first thing I did) yields:

   FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
   FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('string') DO command [command-parameters]  **MAKE NOTE THAT 'string' IS IN *SINGLE QUOTES*!!!**
   FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (command) DO command [command-parameters]

because I just happened to lose the "if usebackq..." line because it just happened to get lost coinciding withe the "press any key..." line in my command prompt window because it just happened to be sized unfortunately (and still doesn't show file-set in standard quotes).

I was asking why quotes wouldn't be used in (file-set) when they are required for spaces and used in (file-set) without /F (i.e. for \%f in ("c\:path w spc\*.txt") do...)

2. I have used that exact syntax in other working batch files. though I went and checked an in each case, %1 or an environment var were in () which apparently settled how quotes were addressed.
3. #1 google search result: [ss64.com/nt/for_f.html](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) which in my frustration I misread the usebackq in reverse and tried ` because it went on to say

> "The backquote character ` is just below the ESC key on most
>   keyboards"

, indicating to me that I was supposed to use that (once or twice) as quotes as seems rational to me if I'm giving direction to use that character.

I am providing this clarification in case it helps others experiencing my frustration.

Those who have "graded me down" for what I believe is legitimate confusion by doing so also prevent me from asking a different question in a totally unrelated area and I would appreciate if they would re-evaluate. I have certainly learned my lesson about unfortunate series' of events.

I understand the reasons that underlie the policy but am very frustrated that 1 time in the years I have been a member being criticized, just for poor luck IMHO, for a question should penalize me apparently 4 or 5 days.

(It's also confusing since since the message says

> It's been 2 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 2 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments.

Does that mean 2 **more** days or the two I have waited?)

So I guess if people want to pound on me for this protest, how many more days can it cost me?

And a further **Thanks!** to *double-beep* for the useful answer even if it wasn't a complete explanation.

Well, back to the penalty box...